# Symfony2 functional test prints out redirect html and stops test execution

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm struggling to understand what is wrong with my functional testing or project settings: the phpunit execution just prints out the following information (I'm not printing this out in the test suite - i.e. it doesn't come from the client->getResponse() printing or anything). Additionally the whole test execution stops immediately without any result information after this text is printed out to the command line:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=/" />

        <title>Redirecting to /</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="/">/</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

After running phpunit from command line:

```
phpunit -c app --group temp1 src/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/SecurityControllerTest.php
```

My test code is rather simple:

```
class SecurityControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
   /**
    * test login with succesfull case
    *
    * @group login
    * @group temp1
    */
    public function testLogin_success()
    {
        $client  = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/'); 

        // temp - just to test that the initial crawler location is correct
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("System Login")')->count(), "login page not found");

        $client->followRedirects(true);

        $crawler = $this->loginSubmit($client, $crawler, "basic_user1@email.com", "basic_user1_password");
        // THE BELOW ROWS ARE NEVER REACHED

        // test that the user can access the user home
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/myprofile');
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Welcome to your user profile")')->count(), "User homepage not accessible after login");
    }

    private function loginSubmit($client, $crawler, $username, $password)
    {        
        $loginButton = $crawler->selectButton('Login');
        $loginForm   = $loginButton->form();
        $loginForm['form[email]']    = $username;
        $loginForm['form[password]'] = $password;

        // BELOW IS THE ROW THAT RESULTS IN THE PRINTOUT + TEST EXECUTION STOP
        return $client->submit($loginForm);
    }

    //....
}
```

Additionally the exactly same test case is working fine on another project that I'm working on so I've been trying to dig out the differences in the project configurations etc without luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated - feel free to ask for some other code / configuration file contents if that might be helpful/relevant.

using symfony 2.3.12 & phpunit 4.1.0

**UPDATED: specific code chain that leads to the error**

So after managing to work around this problem by solving the underlying project session issues couple of days ago, I returned to debug this issue still a bit further. And currently it seems that the result is due to the following code chain, first calling forward:

```
$this->forward('bundle:controller:action')->send();
```

and in the forwarded controller action calling redirect:

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl($route, $parameters))->send();
```

obviously this controller flow seems a bit strange in general, but the question still remains why this leads into the observed result?

Comment: the assertions come after the comment that below rows are never reached. I'll add those to the question as well

Comment: are you checking with default web server or with apache ?

Comment: @GaneshPatil I'm running this from from command line with phpunit (updated the question)

Comment: can you please add assertion after $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/'); this code as well. just check what response you are getting.

Comment: *the exactly same test case is working fine on another project* These things may differ: different versions of dependencies installed by Composer, different server version or configuration.

Comment: @GaneshPatil sure, I tested that locally and added that to the question as well. The login page is as expected for the initial crawler - I checked with $client->getResponse()->getContent() at that point that the crawler is where it should be.

Comment: @A.L yep, I would suspect that the culprit is hidden somewhere along those lines. I've copied most of the configurations already between the projects to test that one out so maybe I still need to just roll up my sleeves and start checking and trying out the differences between the dependencies

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same error and I don't have a code sequence like this.  My testing code hasn't changed but I have updated phpunit and symfony so I believe this is an error with phpunit/symfony code.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when logging-in in a functional test ([official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/3.0/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html)), when i was executing the second time an `$client->request(...)`. Separate those single tests in own test classes did not solve the problem.

I solved this by **not** setting a cookie. Luckily my tests was not depending on a cookie, so all the tests passed than.

Maybe this information would help you, to more isolate your issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer: I managed to get around the issue some days ago with sorting out the session management that was done in the project with a happy mix using session from the request and the php standard session functions (like session_id() - that didn't access the same session in the test environment). I returned now to this original issue and pinpointed the culprit in more details; updated my question as I still don't know what is the exact reason for leading into this result.

Comment: I have the same issue and I think it's being caused by the fact I'm testing the session flashbag during a redirect. The execuation is fine and the test passes but it still has the ugly html output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add some checks in the login function:

```
private function loginSubmit($client, $crawler, $username, $password)
{
    // Check that the HTTP status is good.
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    // Check that there is a form.
    $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('form')->count());

    $loginButton = $crawler->selectButton('Login');
    $loginForm   = $loginButton->form();
    $loginForm['form[email]']    = $username;
    $loginForm['form[password]'] = $password;

    // BELOW IS THE ROW THAT RESULTS IN THE PRINTOUT + TEST EXECUTION STOP
    $crawler = $client->submit($loginForm);

    // Check that the HTTP status is good.
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    // Check that the login is successful, it depends on your code.
    // For example if you show a message "Logged in succesfully." in a <div>:
    $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('div:contains("Logged in succesfully.")')->count());

    // If nothing works, display the rendered HTML to see if there is an error:
    // die($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());

    return $crawler;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, but the resulting behavior with this stays exactly the same. The invocation of $client->submit($loginForm); still prints out the same message and breaks the test execution.

Comment: @ejuhjav :  If we comment  $crawler = $client->submit($loginForm); this code , is it giving  right result for all remaining asserssions?

Comment: @GaneshPatil `$crawler` won't be defined, it will throw a PHP error.

Comment: @GaneshPatil when removing that line, the above answer code will fail at the last assertion check 'Logged in successfully' with normal phpunit assert failure (the $crawler is passed as a function parameter so it won't throw a php error on that)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with the testing code

```
 $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```

I was running an array of relative urls through this assert.  One of the urls was not successful, and my application had a redirect for that case.  Instead of failing the assert, phpunit spits out the RedirectResponse html code and dies.